# Angular 1.4.0 $timeout is not happening after ng-show has taken effect with ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs

I just upgraded to angular 1.4.0 and am having some timing issues with ng-show and $timeout and I’m not sure what the best way to solve it is.

I created a plunkr that demonstrates my situation:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gRIup3mh6kZaZcrfhcEY?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.output = '';
    $scope.toggle = false;

    var outputStuff = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<strong>-----first div shown:" + $scope.toggle + ", second div shown:" + !$scope.toggle + "--------------</strong><br>";
            var firstDivClass = angular.element(document.getElementById("firstDiv")).attr("class");
            var secondDivClass = angular.element(document.getElementById("secondDiv")).attr("class");
            var firstDivOffsetWidth = document.getElementById("firstDiv").offsetWidth;
            var secondDivOffsetWidth = document.getElementById("secondDiv").offsetWidth;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "first div class:" + firstDivClass + "<br>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "second div class:" + secondDivClass + "<br>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "first div width:" + firstDivOffsetWidth + "<br>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "second div width:" + secondDivOffsetWidth + "<br>";
            if ($scope.toggle && firstDivOffsetWidth === 0) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<span style='color:red'>unexpected!!</span><br>";
            }
            if (!$scope.toggle && secondDivOffsetWidth === 0) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<span style='color:red'>unexpected!!</span><br>";
            }

        });
    };

    $scope.toggleVariable = function() {
        $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
        outputStuff();
    };

});
```

Basically, when I click something, I am changing a scope variable that an ng-show depends on.
When the element is shown, I am trying to do something with the element width. However, what I’m observing is inconsistent. Sometimes the element is showing but sometimes it hasn’t been shown yet. Therefore the width is sometimes 0.

If I remove the ngAnimate module from my app, it works as expected; the element that was just set to ng-show=“true”, is in fact shown and has a width.

This used to work fine in Angular 1.3.14 and seems to work all the way up to 1.4.0-rc.2

In the plunkr, you can click on the "click me" button a bunch of times and see that SOMETIMES a red "unexpected!!" text will show up. This is when the element is supposed to be shown but isn't and has a width of 0.

You can remove the 'ngAnimate' module and see that the red text never appears. You can also leave 'ngAnimate' in and change the angular version in index.html to
code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js
and
code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-animate.js
and also see that the red text does not appear. I used Google Chrome to test this.

Why is the timing inconsistent and if $timeout is not the right way to wait for the element to be rendered, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Unhelpful but obligatory comment: DOM manipulation should be done in a directive :)

Comment: In my actual code, it is in the link function of a directive with the same result, but I just wanted it to be simple for the plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error with your demo. However, I came across something similar once before. IIRC, `$timeout` used to use Angular's `$evalAsync` queue, which may not be guaranteed to run after the next redraw. But [this changed recently](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/19b6b3433ae9f8523cbc72ae97dbcf0c06960148). You could try using `$window.setTimeout` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think to answer 'what is the best solution' kind of depends on what it is you're trying to achieve. For instance, an adequate solution would be to simply wait a few extra milliseconds in your `$timeout`. 8 - 10 made it so I never saw `unexpected`

```
$timeout(function () { /* do things */ }, 10)
```

While this may seem like a hack, setTimeout -> 0 (same thing as not providing a ms option) is not that different of a hack. We're just chucking the execution of a function to the end of the event queue.

We could do a combination of timing events to achieve a similar result that might feel less hacky, but in the end gets the same job done.

```
$timeout(function () {
  var intervalPromise = $interval(function () {
    if (element.width) {
      carryOn()
      $interval.cancel(intervalPromise)
    }
  })
})
```

Ultimately you need stuff to happen in the correct order. Because we don't have access to modify the `ng-show` or `ng-animate` apis, we're better off making our code work around it.